# certutil not importing all certs

Tags: certificate

p12 file with 7 certificates in it.
Following the instruction that came along with the cert file, we have to use MMC and a password to import all certs into a personal store.Instruction also says to check mark private key exportable.

in order to automate this, I tried using certutil -importpfx but that only added 4 out of 7 certificates. I am unable to see other 3 certs. The diff i noticed is the imported certs are the ones with "ext issuing CA" and missing certs are with "issuing CA" in the Subject .

Any pointers please

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternate solution using powershell instead of certutil .
Import-pfx with flag -exportable imported all the certs.

Import-PfxCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -Password $Securepwd -FilePath $findP12Cert.FullName -Exportable -Verbose